# Trouble setting value with net-snmp C API

Tags: c, network-programming, snmp, net-snmp

Here is the relevant code:

```
pdu = snmp_pdu_create(SNMP_MSG_SET);

if (snmp_add_var(pdu, oid, oid_len, ASN_INTEGER, "1" ) != 0 )
    snmp_perror("failed");
```

I get an error "Bad value type: **weird Unicode character** "

When I run this snmpset command in terminal:

```
snmpset -v 3 -u <user> <ip> <oid> integer 1
```

it works fine, so why isn't it working in my C program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `snmp_add_var` wrong. It's the equivalent of `snmpset` in a sense, so you should be passing the character `'i'` instead of the constant `ASN_INTEGER`, which is designed for something else.

`ASN_INTEGER` is defined to be `((u_char)0x02)`, so it's the parsing of *that* argument that's causing decoding difficulties.

---

The "something else" is the function you *probably* want to be using instead, which is `snmp_pdu_add_variable`:

```
pdu = snmp_pdu_create(SNMP_MSG_SET);

uint32_t val = 1;
if (snmp_pdu_add_variable(pdu, oid, oid_len, ASN_INTEGER, &val, sizeof(val)) == nullptr)
    snmp_perror("failed");
```

Note how it is "typed", rather than taking a string to lexically convert.